# Code coverage testing tool for iOS

Tags: xcode, instruments

How to do Code Coverage testing in Xcode while using instrument for iOS automation?
 Is there any tool that  display the percentage of the automation code coverage.

Also I would like to know how it can be done when the test cases are written only for functionality.

Comment: For unit test coverage see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14542710/412916

Answer (score 0):

no there isnt. you could include logs and count the number of logs printed vs. the total number of logs.... that would work but is a lot of manual work